# libtbb.so.2 library does not exist when sourcing `compilervars.sh intel64`

Tags: linux, fortran, intel-fortran, tbb, intel-parallel-studio

I am trying to run a file using the `make` command. But when I do this, I get the message:

`make: ifort: Command not found`

I know that I must set the `ifort` environment using the following command:

`/opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2020.1.102/compilers_and_libraries_2020/linux/bin/compilervars.sh intel64`

But when I do this, I get the message:

`ERROR: libtbb.so.2 library does not exist in SUBSTITUTE_INSTALL_DIR_HERE/lib/intel64/gcc4.8.`

Does anyone know what should I do? It looks to me that I must somehow modify the usual variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to inform where gcc4.8 is.

I can manually find it at:`/opt/intel/tbb/lib/intel64/gcc4.8`

Where should I put this information?

I am currently using **Parallel Studio XE 2020**.

Comment: You need to set the apropriate environment variables to `/opt/intel/tbb` instead of `SUBSTITUTE_INSTALL_DIR_HERE` in `tbbvars.sh`.

Comment: How did you install the Parallel Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open

`/opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2020.1.102/compilers_and_libraries_2020/linux/bin/compilervars.sh`

with your favorite editor, and look for the line with `tbb/bin/tbbvars.sh`.

Find the full path for that script. It should be something like

`/opt/intel/parallel_studio_xe_2020.1.102/compilers_and_libraries_2020/linux/tbb/bin/tbbvars.sh`.

Open *that*, and look for the line

`TBBROOT=SUBSTITUTE_INSTALL_DIR_HERE`

and replace with

`TBBROOT="/opt/intel/tbb"`